# Cookie in html webview android

Tags: javascript, android, html, cookies

Hi I need to know is how to read cookies on a html web-view . I have a banner to close it generates a cookie and the idea would be to go to another page that has the banner he would read the cookie to see if the User already have clicked ...

this is the **cookie code**

```
 function createCookie() {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (1*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = "cookie=cookie ; " + expires+';path = http://www.pitstop.com.br/';

    document.getElementById('banner_id').style.display='none';

 }

 function getCookie(cname) {

var name = cname + "=";
var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
}
return null;
 }

 function banner_cookie(){

    var teste = getCookie('cookie');
    if(teste !=null){
        alert(teste);
        document.getElementById('banner_id').style.display='none';

    }else{
        document.getElementById('banner_id').style.display

    }

   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have many issues that seems to stem from wishful thinking and misunderstanding.

For example your path is wrong and you need to pass a name to the cookie script instead of hardcoding the name "cookie"

You need to take a well tested cookie script and use it properly.

```
function getCookie(name) {
  var start = document.cookie.indexOf(name + "=");
  var len = start + name.length + 1;
  if ((!start) && (name != document.cookie.substring(0, name.length))) {
    return null;
  }
  if (start == -1) return null;
  var end = document.cookie.indexOf(';', len);
  if (end == -1) end = document.cookie.length;
  return unescape(document.cookie.substring(len, end));
}

function setCookie(name, value, expires, path, domain, secure) {
  var today = new Date();
  today.setTime(today.getTime());
  if (expires) {
    expires = expires * 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
  }
  var expires_date = new Date(today.getTime() + (expires));
  document.cookie = name + '=' + escape(value) +
    ((expires) ? ';expires=' + expires_date.toGMTString() : '') + //expires.toGMTString()
    ((path) ? ';path=' + path : '') +
    ((domain) ? ';domain=' + domain : '') +
    ((secure) ? ';secure' : '');
}
function deleteCookie(name, path, domain) {
  if (getCookie(name)) document.cookie = name + '=' +
    ((path) ? ';path=' + path : '') +
    ((domain) ? ';domain=' + domain : '') +
    ';expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT';
}
```

Your script:

```
function banner_cookie(){
  var teste = getCookie('showbanner')=="true";
  document.getElementById('banner_id').style.display=teste?"block":"none";
}
```

and to set:

```
setCookie("showbanner","true",14,"/"); // 2 weeks accessible to all website
```

and to remove

```
deleteCookie("showbanner","/");
```